# How to throttle GCDAsyncSocket writes?

Tags: ios, sockets, gcdasyncsocket

Without using tags, how do I correctly write "as fast as possible" but without building up large in-memory buffers of unwritten blobs of data, and how do I keep track of write progress to the OS socket? Should I be using `socket:didWritePartialDataOfLength:tag:` events?

> Called when a socket has written some data, but has not yet completed the entire write. It may be used to for things such as updating progress bars.

Will `GCDAsyncSocket` ever hang on a new write call, because it won't allocate more memory?

How often does that fire? How do I know before queuing a new write, how much is already pending in memory?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, it turned out that actually experimenting was enough.

Write two chunks maximum, and then write a new chunk when you get the callback from GCDAsyncSocket that a chunk has been written. Use the partial data callback to keep track of finer grain progress. Use tags to number the chunks. That's it.